# NSURLRequest delegates not getting called on Device Works fine on simulator.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, nsurlconnection

NSURLRequest delegate methods are not getting called when i run the application on the device. It works perfectly on the simulator though. Also its not the case of my view loading before the request is fulfilled because i enable to view to be loaded only once the connection has received the data.

My code requesting url is here. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://-dev01x/content"]; cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    _getData = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"HELLO %@",_getData);
}
```

Comment: Side note - read docs, if you override `viewWillAppear:` method, you must call super at some point in your implementation. You're not doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as provided here makes no sense:

```
_getData = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

That line returns a pointer to a NSURLConnection object, your variable name is misleading. If you want to block at this point (and does that even work) then it would appear you need to use sendSynchronousRequest at that point.

I do something similar to what you want to do, but in a more traditional way. In viewDidLoad or even in the initWithFrame, I will start up an asynchronous connection, set a flag, and set the view backgroundColor to black or white (I use a spinner too normally). When I get viewWillAppear, if the connection has completed, all is well and I set the various UI elements. If not, then don't do anything, and later, when the connection completes, pull down the spinner and update the UI.

The only way I can think of to block the main thread at the point you are trying to would be to use that synchronous request (which IMHO is a really bad way to deal with this).

The beauty of doing things in the background is that if its taking too long, the user can tap the back button or go somewhere else in the app [in which case you cancel the connection  and tear everything down.]

Answer (score 1):

Check url u provide to NSMutableURLRequest when checked in browser gives nothing

[image]

NSMutableURLRequest needs valid url

Comment: Oh well sorry about that but the url actually works. Meaning its not the URL i have on written up there. Didnt want to expose the URL since its an internal account :( but it works